# ARM: how does linux decompression routine outputs characters on UART?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, arm, uart

Linux decompression routine on ARM uses following code to output messages on console during early boot:

```
static void icedcc_putc(int ch)
{
    int status, i = 0x4000000;

    do {
        if (--i < 0)
            return;

        asm volatile ("mrc p14, 0, %0, c0, c0, 0" : "=r" (status));
    } while (status & 2);

    asm("mcr p14, 0, %0, c1, c0, 0" : : "r" (ch));
}
```

From the [documentation of mcr instruction](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/i/Cihfifej) , it seems like character is move to some coprocessor register.

Please, explain, how does a character eventually gets on uart lines after the last command of icedcc_putc routine.

Comment: It is writing to a coprocessor debug register, which is forwarding it to a defined debug channel (UART). Please read the documentation (upd: link edited): https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0344/k/debug/debug-register-interface/coprocessor-registers-summary

Comment: Looks like it spin-waits for a status then queues a character, with a UART accessible as a coprocessor.

Comment: Output method is both arch and board specific, and requires UART initialization by the bootload program.  See **arch/arm/Kconfig.debug**, and CONFIG_DEBUG_UNCOMPRESS and CONFIG_DEBUG_LL